# Passing an unserializable object to a Handler (from child thread)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, serialization

To give you a bit of history - I'm basically trying to send an unserializable object (Spanned) from the child thread to the main thread (via Message). I tried the obvious - turning it into an array of bytes and sending it that way, but that gives an error since it's not implementing serializable.

Is there any other way I can send it using a Bundle? Or something else?

Here is how I'm sending the message in the child thread

```
// message and bundle for the questions explanation
Message qemsg = messageHandler.obtainMessage();

Bundle qeb = new Bundle();
qeb.putString("questionExplanations", questionExplanations);

qemsg.setData(qeb);
qemsg.arg1 = 0;
messageHandler.sendMessage(qemsg);
```

Here is the main thread handler (receives the messages sent from the child thread):

```
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    CFAData cd = CFAData.getSingletonObject();
    Bundle summaryBundle = msg.getData();

    switch(msg.arg1) {
      case 0:
        // receives the bundle here and does what it needs on the UI thread
        //testQuestionsExplanations.append(spannedExplanationsObj);

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If you have two threads in one process why do you not just simple pass a reference or a clone of the object to be transferred between the threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you attach arbitrary objects to a Message:

```
qemsg.obj = mySpanned;
```